# Parameterless constructing constructorless class (from another assembly)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have this class which is from a NuGet package:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FMUtils.KeyboardHook
{
    public class KeyboardHookEventArgs
    {
        public bool isRShiftPressed { get; }
        public bool isRWinPressed { get; }
        public bool isShiftPressed { get; }
        public bool isWinPressed { get; }
        public Keys Key { get; }

        public override string ToString();
    }
}
```

which is in an assembly which is then referenced by this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FMUtils.KeyboardHook;

namespace SpeedyGonzales
{
    public class MyClass
    {   
        public MyClass()
        {
            var key = new KeyboardHookEventArgs();
        }
    }
}
```

This breaks at compile time, giving me this error:

> 'KeyboardHookEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments

Now there's several things I found about this problem:

1. Every class needs a constructor
2. If you don't explicitly provide **any** constructor, the direct parent's **parameterless** constructor is invoked
3. If parent does not have such constructor, an error is thrown

This seems to be my case, but since my class does not inherit from anything, it means the only direct parent is.. object? And does object not have a parameterless constructor? Please clarify.

Comment: `public override string ToString();` doesn't look right - does this actually compile?

Comment: It's a NuGet package.. pretty used. The code is from inside the given assembly. Why doesnt it look right?

Comment: Class may not have any constructors - it will have a default parameterless one in this case. It looks like you haven't shown the whole code, this code should not even compile.

Comment: Because it doesn't have a body - did you perhaps decompile it from the package?

Comment: @iuliu.net Because method should have a body if it is not abstract.

Comment: I think you need to go re-read what that package is supposed to do for you.  It appears that it's designed with [an internal constructor](https://github.com/factormystic/FMUtils.KeyboardHook/blob/master/Hook.cs#L218) - ie you shouldn't be trying to construct instances of that particular class.

Comment: You are right. You may as well answer this. I never knew what internal constructors were before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code shown in your question does not match the [source in the NuGet package](https://github.com/factormystic/FMUtils.KeyboardHook/blob/master/Hook.cs). The `KeyboardHookEventArgs` class actually contains a constructor which takes a parameter. The signature of this constructor looks like this:

```
internal KeyboardHookEventArgs(FMUtils.KeyboardHook.Hook.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
```

The constructor is marked `internal`, i.e. it is not visible outside of the assembly that contains the declaration (that's why you probably didn't see it in Visual Studio). As a consequence, you can't create an object of type `KeyboardHookEventArgs` directly in your code. This is likely intended by the author of that library (as he explicitly declared the constructor internal).

The [intended usage](https://github.com/factormystic/FMUtils.KeyboardHook) is to use the `Hook` class to create the hook. As you can see, objects of type `KeyboardHookEventArgs` are then created by the `Hook` class and passed to your code as an argument of an event handler:

```
var KeyboardHook = new Hook("Global Action Hook");
KeyboardHook.KeyDownEvent += KeyDown;
// Also: KeyboardHook.KeyUpEvent += KeyUp;

private void KeyDown(KeyboardHookEventArgs e)
{
    // handle keydown event here
    // Such as by checking if e (KeyboardHookEventArgs) matches the key you're interested in

    if (e.Key == Keys.F12 && e.isCtrlPressed)
    {
        // Do your magic...
    }
}
```